# UITableView not reloading on reloadData

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, viewdidload, reloaddata

I have 2 views. The first one has the `UITableView` on it, it loads perfectly, and also if I click my `logOut` method which is triggered through `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it works perfectly.

For the login I have another View, which loads on top as a modal view for Login. Once the login returns success I want it to refresh the menu on `UITableView` from the first view. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

**MenuVC.h**

```
@interface MenuVC : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mainNavigation;
-(void)logOut;
-(void)refreshMenu;
```

**MenuVC.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Aanwezig in viewDidLoad");

    NSUserDefaults *userData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    self.mainNavigation.dataSource = self;
    self.mainNavigation.delegate = self;
    self.mainNavigation.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.menu = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Login",@"Available", @"Downloads", @"FAQ", nil];

    if ( [userData objectForKey:@"userId"] != nil ) {

        [self.menu removeObject:@"Login"];

        [self.menu insertObject:[userData objectForKey:@"email"] atIndex:0];
        [self.menu insertObject:@"Logout" atIndex:1];

        signedInSuccess = YES;

    } 

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"menuCell";
    MenuCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[MenuCell alloc]initWithStyle:
              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if ( signedInSuccess == YES && indexPath.row == 0 ) {
        NSLog(@"Disabled: %@", [self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.menuTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    } else {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        cell.menuTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    }


    cell.menuTextLabel.text = [self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Logout and refreshMenu both work here
    if ( [identifier isEqualToString:@"Logout"] ) {
        NSLog("Logout button clicked");
        [self logOut];
        [self refreshMenu];

    }

    //Rest of the code

}

-(void)refreshMenu {

    [self viewDidLoad];
    [self.mainNavigation reloadData];

}

-(void)logOut {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"userId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"email"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"password"];
    signedInSuccess = NO;

}
```

The codes above all work, only here is the problem occurring, when I click `loginClicked`, and call `refreshMenu` it IS doing [self viewDidLoad], but **NOT** `[self.mainNavigation reloadData];` from the `refreshMenu` method.

**LoginVC.m**

```
#import "MenuVC.h"

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
{    
         // If login process is success (which works)
         MenuVC *MenuViewController = [[MenuVC alloc] init];
         [MenuViewController refreshMenu];
}
```

Comment: Well, first of all, you shouldn't call `[self viewDidLoad];` Then, you did a init of `MenuVC`. Is that the same object of the previous one?

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the tableview or the data source ?

Comment: remove the [self viewDidLoad]; from menurefresh methods dont call viewDidload anywhere in your user defined methods in implementation class..

Comment: Instead of calling [MenuViewController refreshMenu] after alloc, call the method [self.mainNavigation reloadData]; in viewDidLoad of MenuVC.m

Comment: I have added a bit more code just to clear things up, hope this helps to get me some help in fixing this..
@Larme, if I remove that, when I click on the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath - LogOut" doesn't work anymore. 
Macaret, yes I did.
user2071152 That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ' viewDidLoad ' is called only once in the viewController. User separate ViewControllers forlogin and menu. don't call [self viewDidLoad];

Comment: @VineeshTP I am using different view controllers for Login and Menu. As you can see the first two are MenuVC, the last one is LoginVC. I just need a way to do a refresh of the data and reload the table view FROM LoginVC TO MenuVC.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: 
You don't call yourself `viewDidLoad`. So remove it in `refreshMenu`, and if you want other code that you put in `viewDidLoad` transform it in a method that you'll call in `viewDidLoad` and that you could also call in `refreshMenu`

The issue, is that you have an object `MenuVC` already created. When in LoginVC.m you do `MenuVC *MenuViewController = [[MenuVC alloc] init];` it's a whole new object. It isn't even on screen. That not the same object that the previous one. If you doubt it, check their pointers.

If I understood correctly, your `MenuVC` object is the owner of the `LoginVC` object.

So, a solution you can use is the delegate pattern.
Here a suggestion you can adapt.

In LoginVC.h

```
@protocol LoginVCDelegate < NSObject >
-(void)didLoginWithSuccess:(BOOL)success;
@end
@property (nonatomic, week) id < LoginVCDelegate > loginDelegate;
```

In LoginVC.m, in `loginClicked:`

```
if ([_loginDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didLoginWithSuccess:)])
    [_loginDelegate didLoginWithSuccess:theBooleanYouWant];
```

In MenuVC.h

```
@interface MenuVC : UIViewController< UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, LoginVCDelegate >
```

In MenuVC.m

```
-(void)didLoginWithSuccess:(BOOl)success
{
    [self refreshMenu];
    //Note that you could check if login succeed or not by checking the success boolean.
}
```

Also, when LoginVC is created in MenuVC.m:

```
[loginVC setLoginVCDelegate:self];
```